# VSTS REST pushes api returns 409

Tags: git, rest, azure-devops

I am trying to update a file in my repo using pushes api but always get 409 response. Please advise if I do something wrong.

Here is the request:

```
POST  https://{myaccount}.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/{myteam}/_apis/git/repositories/{myrepo}/pushes?api-version=3.0 HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Basic <token>
Host: {myaccount}.visualstudio.com
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 493

{
  "commits": [
    {
      "Comment": "Some comment",
      "Changes": [
        {
          "Item": {
            "Path": "somepath/test.json"
          },
          "ChangeType": 1,
          "NewContent": {
            "Content": "test"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "refUpdates": [
    {
      "name": "refs/heads/somebranch",
      "oldObjectId": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    }
  ]
}
```

and I got 409 response:

```
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF401028: The reference 'refs/heads/mybranch' has already been updated by another client, so you cannot update it. Please try again.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Server.GitReferenceStaleException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Server","typeKey":"GitReferenceStaleException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
```

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` oldObjectId, it is used to create a new branch, otherwise you need to specify the commit sha.

1. Go to the code page > Files
2. Choose a repository and branch
3. Select the root level (repository name) > History
4. Click … of the first commit > Copy full SHA

Answer (score 0):

Is correct:

For 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 oldObjectId, it is used to create a new branch, otherwise you need to specify the commit sha.

1. Go to the code page > Files
2. Choose a repository and branch
3. Select the root level (repository name) > History
4. Click … of the last commit > Copy full SHA

But, should be the full SHA of the last published commit from the branch you want to use, not the first commit.